# Write array to CSV inside arc script tool (works in pycharm, doesn't work in arc)

Tags: csv, numpy, toolbox

I have an arcpy script in which I am writing an array to a CSV (for later use in the script to make a routeing layer).

I've tried a couple iterations, and all work like a charm in PyCharm (can't pass up a pun, no matter how weak). But when I convert to script tool and run in the catalog in ArcMap 10.6, it doesn't write the CSV. (Other numpy operations work fine.) In my multiple scripting attempts, the CSV file is opened and headers are written fine; it poops out on writing the array.

When I check x.shape in PyCharm, it shows the right dimensions (91L, 4L)
When I check x.shape in Arc python shell, it shows the wrong dimensions [0, 4]

I don't understand why ArcGIS sees the array as empty.

```
nom_rup = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
route_offset_km = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
route_ptsSpacing_km = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
eqk_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
target_epsg = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
outpath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)


# in arc script tool, fields defined as follows:
# nom_rup > shapefile [note not needed for this self-contained snippet; so can browse to any SHP]
# route_offset_km > double, I entered 5
# route_ptsSpacing_km > double, I entered 1
# eqk_name > string [note not needed for this self-contained snippet; so can enter abc123]
# target_epsg > double [note not needed for this self-contained snippet; so can enter 12345]
# outpath > folder, I browsed to my output folder

rup_len_km = 89.932 # this is calculated elsewhere in the script, so I define it here in this self-contained snippet

start = 0
import numpy
stop1 = (numpy.ceil(rup_len_km) + 1) * 1000
step = route_ptsSpacing_km * 1000

start = float(start)
stop1 = float(stop1)
step = float(step)

# Execute
descritizings = numpy.arange(start, stop1, step)

# Clean up
del start, stop1, step

off1 = numpy.full((len(descritizings)), route_offset_km * 1000)
off2 = numpy.full((len(descritizings)), route_offset_km * -1000)
rt = numpy.ones((len(descritizings)))

route_table = numpy.array([descritizings, off1, rt, off2])
route_table = route_table.transpose()


outFile = outpath + '\\' + '_RouteTable.csv'
numpy.savetxt(outFile, route_table, fmt = '%d', delimiter = ',', header = "LOCATION, OFFSET1, ROUTE, OFFSET2", comments = '')
```

if I use

```
off1 = numpy.ones((len(descritizings))) * route_offset_km * 1000
off2 = numpy.ones((len(descritizings))) * route_offset_km * -1000
```

instead, as suggested in a comment below, here's the error I get (note line 170 is from the longer script but corresponds to the line that begins with "off1..."

[image]

Comment: I also tried the following to write the csv file:

<<<<<

heads = ['LOCATION', 'OFFSET1', 'ROUTE', 'OFFSET2']
import csv

# writing to csv file
with open(outFile, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

    # writing the fields
    csvwriter.writerow(heads)

    # writing the data rows
    csvwriter.writerows(route_table)

>>>>>

when running it through the arc script, it still produces a CSV as shown above (i.e., writes headers but that's all) (EDIT, I don't know why this is showing up collapsed and hard to read, apologies)

Comment: the script is 500 lines long, I assumed no one would want to read through the first 215 lines or the last 260 lines. Editing now based on more troubleshooting.

Comment: edited; works in pycharm. if I add print route_table.shape it shows correct dimensions in pycharm. if I add arcpy.AddMessage(route_table.shape) it shows incorrect (empty) dimensions in arc

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Just recognized that in my arc tool, I am entering these values... so, it has been edited again. Maybe the issue is I am entering some values as "double" in the arc tool script? not sure what other type to use? thx

Comment: true that!! awesome, let me give it a whirl--when I have luck, I'll let you know and you maybe you can convert the comment to an answer so I can upvote it

Comment: woohoo, it worked! only slight variation--I got a bust on use of "var =" inside there, but this worked: route_offset_km = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1))        many many thanks, I'll be sure to mark this as the solution if ya add it as an answer. thank you!!

Comment: "var" was just a throwaway, meant to be replaced by your *actual* variable name ans index by your actual parameter index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetParameterAsText` returns the parameter values "as text".

Use

```
var = int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(index))
```

and/or

```
var = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(index))
```

to convert the numeric parameter text to the appropriate type of number.

Replace `var` with your actual variable name as appropriate.